# tabhost not displaying tabs in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

tab bar is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I use the below code to create tabs.While running its not displaying tabs its showing  white screen even though it shows in emulator

```
public class tab_content : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.tabmenu);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;     
        Intent intent;   
        intent = new Intent (this, typeof (rate1));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("tab1");
        spec.SetIndicator ("Check In", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_artists));

        spec.SetContent (intent);
        TabHost.AddTab (spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent (this, typeof (rate2));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("tab2");
        spec.SetIndicator ("Guest Room", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_artists));
        spec.SetContent (intent);

        TabHost.AddTab (spec);


        intent = new Intent (this, typeof ( rate3));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("tab3");
        spec.SetIndicator ("Laundry and Valet", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_artists));
        spec.SetContent (intent);

        TabHost.AddTab (spec);

        TabHost.CurrentTab = 0;
    }
}
```

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you assign `TabHost`.

Comment: in the above code i have assigned tabhost

Comment: You don't have a `TabHost` assignment like `TabHost = blabla;` anywhere. If you look carefully in any walkthrough you have to use `TabActivity` to get that piece of code you have to work.